# Domain object getting mocked?

Tags: java, mocking, jmockit

Here is mine EmployeeServiceTest.java

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class EmployeeServiceTest {

    @Tested
    private EmployeeServiceImpl employeeService;

    @Injectable
    private EmployeeDaoImpl employeeDao;

    @Test
    public void testGetEmployee() {

        Employee employee= new Employee();
        employee.setAddress("Test Address");

        new Expectations() {
            {
                employeeDao.get(Employee.class, 1L);result = employee;
            }
        };

        Employee employee1 = employeeService.getEmployee(1L);
        System.out.println(employee1.getAddress()); // Line 1   
    }
}
```

Here is mine `EmployeeServiceImpl`.java

```
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeDao employeeDao;

    public Employee getEmployee(Long id) {
        return employeeDao.get(Employee.class, id);
    }
}
```

Issue is when I do `System.out.println(employee.getAddress())` at `line no1`, I get address as null instead of `Test Address`. I am not sure what
the issue here?

Comment: You could make your class to test more simple and readable with a public api that allows to provide the dependency.

Comment: Post `EmployeeDao ` code please.

Comment: And something is awkward here: your test uses ´EmplyeeServiceImpl` - but then you are showing us a `EmployeeService` production class?! Long story short: [mcve]  please!

Comment: @davidxxx Not sure what you mean here ? I returned actual domain object not mocked one with  `result = employee` but still when I do  `System.out.println(employee.getAddress()); ` in my test I Get null value. I am not sure employee is getting mocked here ?

Comment: @GhostCat It was typo error. Corrected it.

Comment: The code works fine for me... Which version of JMockit you used? Anyway, I suspect the real issue is something else, since the code shown doesn't compile without a couple fixes (there are two `employee` variables declared, and the `1` id needs to be `1L`).

Comment: @Rogério I am using `Jmockit 1.20 ` . Regarding the compilation issues you mentioned, I corrected them in above post(mentioned issues are not issues in actual code but  issues becoz of mine typing in above post)

Comment: Guys I Got my mistake I had `@Mocked Employee employee` as instance variable which was causing to mock every method of employee class. Removed instance variable